# Speeding up a minimisation involving Numeric integral and Interpolating function

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, fitting, interpolation

I am doing a minimisation procedure to obtain best fit parameters `a,b,NN` for a model involving a numeric integral and an interpolation function. The code as written below runs but I am yet to obtain a result because of time issues. I've used a combination of answers by @JimB in fitting and @J.M for interpolating functions to obtain the below but I still can't see a way to speed up the computation. Any suggestions or changes I can make to the below would be great. Thanks.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

MasData5 = {{{44.8, 47.5}, ErrorBar[4.0]}, {{54.8, 50.1}, 
ErrorBar[4.2]}, {{64.8, 61.7}, ErrorBar[5.1]}, {{74.8, 64.8}, 
ErrorBar[5.5]}, {{84.9, 75}, ErrorBar[6.2]}, {{94.9, 81.2}, 
ErrorBar[6.7]}, {{104.9, 85.3}, ErrorBar[7.1]}, {{119.5, 94.5}, 
ErrorBar[7.5]}, {{144.1, 101.5}, ErrorBar[8.3]}, {{144.9, 101.9}, 
ErrorBar[10.9]}, {{162.5, 117.8}, 
ErrorBar[12.8]}, {{177.3, 130.2}, 
ErrorBar[13.4]}, {{194.8, 147.7}, 
ErrorBar[17.1]}, {{219.6, 137.4}, 
ErrorBar[20.1]}, {{244.8, 176.6}, 
ErrorBar[20.3]}, {{267.2, 178.7}, 
ErrorBar[21.1]}, {{292.3, 200.4}, ErrorBar[29.1]}, {{60, 55.8}, 
ErrorBar[4.838]}, {{80, 66.6}, ErrorBar[7.280]}, {{100, 73.4}, 
ErrorBar[6.426]}, {{120, 86.7}, ErrorBar[7.245]}, {{140, 104}, 
ErrorBar[12.083]}, {{160, 110}, ErrorBar[16.279]}, {{42.5, 43.8}, 
ErrorBar[3.482]}, {{55, 57.2}, ErrorBar[3.980]}, {{65, 62.5}, 
ErrorBar[4.614]}, {{75, 68.9}, ErrorBar[5.197]}, {{85, 72.1}, 
ErrorBar[5.523]}, {{100, 81.9}, ErrorBar[5.368]}, {{117.5, 95.7}, 
ErrorBar[6.277]}, {{132.5, 103.9}, ErrorBar[6.912]}, {{155, 115}, 
ErrorBar[7.920]}, {{185, 129.1}, ErrorBar[9.192]}, {{215, 141.7}, 
ErrorBar[10.666]}, {{245, 140.3}, ErrorBar[14.526]}, {{275, 189}, 
ErrorBar[24.274]}, {{49, 39.2}, ErrorBar[10]}, {{86, 75.7}, 
ErrorBar[14.414]}, {{167, 118}, ErrorBar[22.828]}, {{43.2, 50.7}, 
ErrorBar[1.5]}, {{50, 59.5}, ErrorBar[1.4]}, {{57.3, 61.8}, 
ErrorBar[1.9]}, {{65.3, 67.6}, ErrorBar[1.7]}, {{73.9, 72.4}, 
ErrorBar[1.9]}, {{83.2, 79.9}, ErrorBar[2.3]}, {{93.3, 84.4}, 
ErrorBar[2.1]}, {{104.3, 86.7}, ErrorBar[2.7]}, {{47.9, 55.4}, 
ErrorBar[2.1]}, {{68.4, 66.4}, ErrorBar[2.9]}};
(*h1 2006 Q^2=0 data,zeus 2002,zeus 2004 and h1 2013 data for Q^2=0*)

gamma = 5.55*^-6;
MJpsi = 3.10;
alphaem = 1/137;
lambda = 0.09;
Ca = 3

xg = NN x^-a k^b Exp[Sqrt[(16 Ca)/9 Log[1/x] Log[Log[k/lambda]/Log[qo/lambda]]]];

diff = -x*D[Log[xg], x] // Simplify

diffx = diff /. x -> ((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2)
```

I then generate a table of values (called dataset) using an external package and create an interpolating function cubic1

```
cubic1 = Interpolation[dataset];

 f51[w_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, NN_?NumericQ] := ((NIntegrate[
cubic1[k]/
   2.4025/(2.4025 + 
    k)*((2^((
     2.309401076758503` Sqrt[
      Log[0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
           w^2)] Log[
        0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])]])/
     Log[0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
         0.25` w^2)]) 2.4025`^-a E^(
     2.309401076758503` Sqrt[
      Log[0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
           w^2)] Log[
        0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])]])
      k^(-1 + b)
      NN (1/(-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + w^2))^-a Gamma[
      5/2 + a + (1.1547005383792515` \[Sqrt](Log[
              0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
                w^2)] Log[
              0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + 
                Log[k])]))/
        Log[0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
            0.25` w^2)]] (10.868302641207583` b (2.407945608651872` + Log[k]) Log[
         0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
            w^2)] Log[
         0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])] + 

       4.51351666838205` b Log[
         k] (2.407945608651872` + Log[k]) Log[
         0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
            w^2)] Log[
         0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])] + 
       3.6125168377601704` (2.407945608651872` + 
          Log[k]) \[Sqrt](Log[
            0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
               w^2)] Log[
            0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])]) + 
       12.549634911071038` Log[
         0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
            0.25` w^2)] \[Sqrt](Log[
            0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
               w^2)] Log[
            0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])]) + 
       5.211760126964479` Log[k] Log[
         0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
            0.25` w^2)] \[Sqrt](Log[
            0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
               w^2)] Log[
            0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])]) + 
       2.6058800634822394` (2.407945608651872` + 
          Log[k]) \[Sqrt](Log[
            0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
               w^2)] Log[

            0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + 
               Log[k])]) PolyGamma[0, 
         5/2 + a + (1.1547005383792515` \[Sqrt](Log[
                0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
                w^2)] Log[
                0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + 
                Log[k])]))/
           Log[0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
               0.25` w^2)]] - 
       2.6058800634822394` (2.407945608651872` + 
          Log[k]) \[Sqrt](Log[
            0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
               w^2)] Log[
            0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + 
               Log[k])]) PolyGamma[0, 
         4 + a + (1.1547005383792515` \[Sqrt](Log[
                0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
                w^2)] Log[
                0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + 
                Log[k])]))/
           Log[0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
               0.25` w^2)]]))/(Gamma[
      4 + a + (1.1547005383792515` \[Sqrt](Log[
              0.10405827263267431` (-1.7763568394002505`*^-15 + 
                w^2)] Log[
              0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + 
                Log[k])]))/
        Log[0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
            0.25` w^2)]] (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])^2 Log[
      0.41623309053069724` (-4.440892098500626`*^-16 + 
         0.25` w^2)] Log[
      0.4152917725412687` (2.407945608651872` + Log[k])])), {k, 
 1, (w^2 - MJpsi^2)/4}, 
Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", 
  "MaxSubregions" -> 25000}]))
```

I used method InterpolationPointsSubDivision as suggested in a post by @J.M

```
  f52[w_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, NN_?NumericQ] :=((0.118/2.4025/1*Log[(2.4025 + 1)/2.4025]*
NN*((4*2.4025)/((4*2.4025 - MJpsi^2) + w^2))^(-a)*(1)^b*(2^(2*((a))
      + 3)/Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[((a))
     + 5/2]/Gamma[((a))
     + 4])))

  F5[w_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ,  NN_?NumericQ] := (3.89379*^5*1/(4.9 + 4*0.06*Log[w/90])/16*4*Pi^3*
MJpsi^3*gamma/12/alphaem)*(f51[w, a, b, NN] + f52[w, a, b, NN])^2

   chisq5[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, NN_?NumericQ] = Sum[((MasData5[[j, 1, 2]] - F5[MasData5[[j, 1, 1]], a, b, NN])/
 MasData5[[j, 2, 1]])^2, {j, 1, Length[MasData5]}]

  NMinimize[{chisq5[a, b, NN], {a, b, NN}, MaxIterations -> 100] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The dataset needed to create interpolating function is rather long. I couldn't upload the data because of its longevity but perhaps there is a way to upload a notebook on here?

In the interim Jack LaVigne uploaded a minimal working `dataset` that can be retrieved by pasting and executing the link below in your notebook. This `datset` is 2500 values. The actual `dataset` is 25000 values.

Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtgz9.png"]

After it appears execute:

```
dataset = {{1, 0.45602422848985647028},
           {239/25, 0.17975228259494189868}, ...
```

Comment: @JimB From your experience of fitting, would you be able to help here?